# Typeahead.js suggestions aren't filtered

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using [**Typeahead.js**](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) to select item names I'm retrieving (through Bloodhound) from a PHP/Mysql page, for one of my input fields.

When I type in the input field, the suggestion always shown 5 first row **without filtering**, however the highlight does appear to be working correctly (see screenshot below).

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

#### My JS :

```
var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('item_name', 'item_code'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    //local: jsonData
    remote  : {
        url:'function/load-item.php?item_name=%QUERY',
    }
});

dataSource.initialize();

$('#item_name').typeahead({
    minLength : 3,
    highlight : true
}, {
    limit : 25,
    name : 'countries',
    display : function(item) {
        return item.item_name
    },
    source : dataSource.ttAdapter(),
    suggestion : function(data) {}
});

$('#item_name').on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
    console.log(datum);
    $('#item_code').val(datum.item_code);
});
```

#### My PHP :

```
session_start();
include ('../include/connect.php');
$query = "SELECT item_name, item_code FROM master_item";

$return = array();
if($result = $conn->query($query)){
    // fetch array
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $return[] = $row;
    }

    // free result set
    $result->close();
    // close connection
    $conn->close();

    $json = json_encode($return);
    print_r($json);
}
```

#### My Json output :

```
[{
    "item_name":"wrench",
    "item_code":"aa"
}, {
    "item_name":"compressor",
    "item_code":"bb"
}, {
    "item_name":"grinder",
    "item_code":"cc"
}, {
    "item_name":"air con",
    "item_code":"dd"
}, {
    "item_name":"handphone",
    "item_code":"ee"
}, {
    "item_name":"refreigrator",
    "item_code":"ff"
}]
```

Comment: What version of Typeahead are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add `sufficient` to your initializer and set its value to **0**.
Also, there is an extra comma in your code after the remote url parameter.

```
var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('item_name', 'item_code'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  sufficient: 0,
  remote  : {
    url:'function/load-item.php?item_name=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it;s not working mate, the suggestion still not filtering

Comment: Have you tried using `source: dataSource` instead of `source: dataSource.ttAdapter()`?

Comment: not working too. do you think my query is correct ? because i think maybe it need a LIKE

Comment: I think you should isolate the problem first by testing your PHP script alone before using typeahead.js. If your script is working as expected, then start troubleshooting your typeahead.js implementation against your PHP script.

Comment: i updated the php result above, please take a look, thank you